# Author's first name is surname

Tags: bibtex, revtex

The author list for [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.12965.pdf) is Sebastian Scherg, Thomas Kohlert, Pablo Sala, Frank Pollmann, Bharath H. M., Immanuel Bloch, Monika Aidelsburger. I'm using revtex4-2 and whichever bibliographystyle it uses by default. It currently abbreviates the fifth name as B. Hebbe Madhusudhana but I would like it to instead abbreviate it as Bharath H. M.
My MWEB is

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
   journal=Journal,
   author={Scherg, Sebastian and Kohlert, Thomas and Sala, Pablo and Pollmann, Frank and Hebbe Madhusudhana, Bharath and Bloch, Immanuel and Aidelsburger, Monika}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{key}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

How can I tell it to a) not abbreviate Bharath and b) abbreviate H. M.?

Comment: Please augment your code to make it minimally compilable. Please also be sure to state which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: BibTeX's name handling is pretty much tailored to Western names. That means it assumes that names consist of a first and a last name with natural order "First Last" and inverted/sorting order "Last, First" where in both cases "First" may be abbreviated to an initial only. (BibTeX also supports junior parts and "von" parts.) If a name does not fit this scheme things can get tricky. It is always possible to force one particular representation with curly braces, i.e. `{Bharath H. M.}`, but then the name is not analysed into parts and cannot be abbreviated automatically.

Comment: I suppose that'll be good enough for now. Thank you.